# Problem while importing with pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a problem while importing data with pandas. 
Here is the situation. I have a file which I have to skip the initial 40 lines.
Afterwards, it needs to separate the data with ';' and use ',' as a decimal.
Then, the first and second columns should be assigned to the variable x and y, respectively.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', skiprows=40, header=None,engine='python', decimal=",")
# Separates the data into x vector and y vector
x=data.loc[:,0].values
y=data.loc[:,1].values
```

The data vector comes out as:

```
   0  29.49486      0.10915     -0.30708
   1  30.45667      0.17562     -0.30724
   2 31.41848       0.23216     -0.30735
   3 32.38029       0.27814     -0.30750
   4 33.34211       0.31412     -0.30764
   5 34.30390       0.34117     -0.30794
   .
   .
   .
166  189.15537      0.41301     -0.16899
167  190.11718      0.41302     -7,7716e-002
168  191.07899                   2,7883e-002
```

Everything, except the last 2 lines are imported as expected.

when assigning the vectors to variables with:

```
  x=data.loc[:,0].values
  y=data.loc[:,1].values
```

I get the x vector as float64 and the y as an object.

What am I doing wrong while importing?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Did you check with your original file? I suspect the last 2 values are formatted differently in the original and pandas does not know how to handle them and therefore imports them as strings, which makes your second column an object as it no longer has a unique data type

Comment: In the original file the last two lines are as:
`190,11718;    0,41302; -7,7716e-002;
191,07899;                 ; 2,7883e-002;`

Comment: Did you try to change it to `float`via `y.astype(np.float64)`?